# Is there a way to close Experience Manager and return to normal staging site browsing?

Tags: 2013, experience-manager

Some Editors find it more convenient to browse through the staging website normally, then pop in and out of XPM when wanting to make edits. They can pop in to the XPM interface easily by clicking the SDL Tridion button in the top left corner, but I didnt find a way to close XPM and return to normal staging browsing (on the current XPM page in context), other then typing in the URL in the browser address bar, which seems a bit clumsy. Is this possible?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The log out is a little tucked away, you have to return to the 'dashboard' tab/view and in the left hand navigation the bottom link 'Exit', clicking that will close XPM and return you back to the website on the page you were editing.

Comment: SDL Tridion 2013 SP1 (due in a few weeks) presents a close button on the main toolbar too...

Answer (score 1):

As Nuno mentions in his comment above, the close button in now on the right hand side of the main toolbar:

[image]